# resetting all select2 jquery select elements

Tags: jquery

I need to reset couple of select2 select element. Currently i am doing it as follows

```
            $("#ItemId").select2("val", "");
            $("#PermanentDistrictId").select2("val", "");
            $("#PermanentThanaId").select2("val", "");
            $("#PresentDistrictId").select2("val", "");
            $("#PresentThanaId").select2("val", "");
            $("#OccupationId").select2("val", "");
            $("#GenderId").select2("val", "");
```

But i would like to do it in single function like as follows-

```
ParticularForm.AllSelectElements.select2("val", "");
```

I am asking here as because my javascript skill is very poor. So, I need your help.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try `$('#yourform select').select2("val", "");`

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, thanks. It works. Please post it as answer so that i can accept.

Comment: Glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ParticularForm.AllSelectElements` can be done as follows:

```
$('#yourform select').select2("val", "");
```

This selects all `<select>` elements inside `#yourform`.

Comment: If i want to use a form variable instead of form name, how can i do that? i.e. $('form select').select2("val", "");

Comment: @SKPaul: What do you mean "form variable"?  What would be in this variable?

Comment: var form = $('#MyForm');
form.trigger('reset');
$('form select').select2("val", "");

Comment: @SKPaul: In that case you can do: `$('select', form).select2("val", "");`

Answer (score 6):

$(".select2-hidden-accessible").val(null).trigger("change");

Answer (score 1):

Just `trigger` the `change.select2` event with `.trigger('change.select2')`

```
$(document).on('click','[type="reset"]', function (e){
                $(this)
                    .closest('form')
                    .find('select')
                    .val(null)
                    .trigger('change.select2');
            });
```